# Compare a credential secret against a known value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, credentials

Suppose I have a SQL Server [Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) saved in the database with a specific secret.  I want to only modify the credential if the secret saved in the database is different from the actual secret.

Sometimes, an example is good, so take a look at this:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [MyCred]
WITH IDENTITY = N'DOMAIN\User'
    , SECRET = N'some_password';
```

So, after the password for `DOMAIN\User` is changed from `some_password` to `some_new_password`, I need to update the secret, but only if the stored value does not match. i.e. I don't want to blindly drop and recreate the credential.

With server principals, I can use the `LOGINPROPERTY([login_name], 'PasswordHash')` function to get the hashed version of the encrypted password stored in the master database, but that doesn't seem to work for credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encrypted Credential passwords can be seen via DAC:-

```
SELECT *
FROM [master].sys.sysobjvalues
WHERE valclass = 28;
```

They aren't stored the same way as Login passwords, they're encrypted using the Service Master Key (SMK).

This post goes further, and links to a PowerShell script to decrypt them:-

https://www.netspi.com/blog/technical/adversary-simulation/decrypting-mssql-credential-passwords/

You could automate the running of the PowerShell script to export the cleartext passwords for comparison.

Maybe a simpler way is to just check the [modify_date] of sys.credentials, if the date is earlier than a known password change (assuming you knew it had been changed), you'd know you needed to update the Credential.

If you're dealing with AD passwords, you can use Get-ADUser to find the password change date to compare with, but this gets trickier to get a reliable result under more complex AD environments.

Comment: thanks Rob, this is for a DevOps deployment pipeline, so it's not using the DAC.  I like the idea of checking the accounts password change date, and comparing that to the credentials `modify_date` column.

Comment: Be careful using that approach, it's not entirely correct: https://www.seangallardy.com/dbatools-decryption-issues-are-not-a-sql-server-bug/